# Cannot start services : Running in chroot, ignoring request

Tags: systemd, services, ubuntu-core, chroot

I am working with Ubuntu Core using snap classic mode.

I want to use some services, like Docker. I managed to install it, but when I try to start it (with `sudo service docker start`) or just even get the status, I have the following message:

`Running in chroot, ignoring request`

What does this message mean ? How can I start these services ?

Many thanks

Comment: You may refer [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/chromeos/comments/9xp44a/ubuntu_in_crouton_running_in_chroot_ignoring/)  and also [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/docker/comments/9xooil/systemctl_start_docker_runing_in_chroot_ignoring/).